# Creating an object only once and updating

Tags: c#, wpf, writeablebitmap

I'm kind new to c#.

I have this code:

```
        public static BitmapSource FromNativePointer(IntPtr pData, int w, int h, int ch)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat format = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default;

            if (ch == 1) format = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray8; //grey scale image 0-255
            if (ch == 3) format = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgr24; //RGB
            if (ch == 4) format = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgr32; //RGB + alpha

            WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(w, h, (double)96, (double)96, format, null);

            CopyMemory(wbm.BackBuffer, pData, (uint)(w * h * ch));

            wbm.Lock();
            wbm.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, wbm.PixelWidth, wbm.PixelHeight));
            wbm.Unlock();

            return wbm;
        }
```

I'm having some memory problem with the wbm variable.
How can I create the variable outside this function and then update its parameters only when I get in the function?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the memory problem you are having?

Comment: If you want to avoid the `new WriteableBitmap(...)`, you're going to have to implement it yourself using `Bitmap` and `BitmapData`, with some `MAX_WIDTH` and `MAX_HEIGHT`. Then, you can save it as a field and reuse it every time you need it. Note that this isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it a global/static variable.

```
public class Example(){
      public static WriteableBitmap wbm;
      .
      .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `wbm` as an additional parameter to the method.  You don't even have to `return` it if you declare it in your parameter list as a `ref`:

```
public static void
    FromNativePointer(ref BitmapSource wbm, IntPtr pData, int w, int h, int ch)
```

If you declare it this way, you must also call it using `ref`:

```
FromNativePointer(ref mywbm, mypData ... etc.
```

Comment: And how will it be changed whenever he needs, according to `w` and `h`?

Comment: What? He's already written the code to do that.  Obviously, if a new `BitmapSource` is needed, a `new` `BitmapSource` will have to be created.

Comment: I don't wanna have to create a new wbm variable every time I get in this function. I wanna just update it. But I cant create like that `WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(w, h, (double)96, (double)96, format, null);` outside the function because it will ask for w, h and format

Comment: I tried your way but once I add `ref BitmapSource wbm` I get errors cause I lose de definition of `BackBuffer` `Lock` `AddDirtyRect` `Unlock`